# How to check when Azure SQL Serverless instance is paused retroactively?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Basically title, I have a bunch of Azure SQL Serverless instances which are all configured to be auto-paused after 1 hour of inactivity. Is it possible to check if/when the pauses happen retroactively? For example in last week, last 30 days and so on. I know I can easily check CURRENT status of each database, but I cannot find a way to do so for past periods. HELP!

I've googled the crap out of this question and can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your questions, do the follow:

Go to the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com), navigate to your Azure SQL Serverless instance, and then find the Monitoring section. From there, you can explore metrics and set up metric alerts.

Or, you can also use Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell to programmatically retrieve metrics and logs data.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceId == "<your_serverless_instance_resource_id>"
| where Category == "SqlServer"
| where OperationName == "AUTO PAUSE"
| where TimeGenerated >= datetime("2024-01-01T00:00:00Z") and TimeGenerated <= datetime("2024-01-07T23:59:59Z")
| project TimeGenerated, ResourceId, OperationName
```

Replace <your_sql_serverless_instance_resource_id> with the resource ID of your Azure SQL Serverless instance. Adjust the time range (datetime("2024-01-01T00:00:00Z") and datetime("2024-01-07T23:59:59Z")) according to the period you want to query.

Comment: Hi Ricardo,  yes- this is exactly what I'm looking for. I installed Azure CLI and currently am trying to run the query you've suggested. I've pasted your query and replaced the resource ID - however - I am running into this error:

An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:3 char:1
+ | where Category == "SqlServer"
+ ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:4 char:1
+ | where OperationName == "AUTO PAUSE"
+ ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:5 char:1

I had to cut out some of the error due to length restriction. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would go to azure portal, select the database and go to the metrics chart. It also gives us the option to choose the timeframe you want and the granularity.

[image: Metrics screenshot]